# ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter inside Fragment crashes Application when starting Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter inside a Fragment, which I display inside a FrameLayout.
Everything works fine so far, I can swap between Fragments inside my FrameLayout with no problems at all.

BUT if I flick the ViewPager and then fast swap to a different Fragment mid animation, I this Error and the App crashes:

```
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a002f for fragment NewsPagerFragment{4184f340 #4 id=0x7f0a002f android:switcher:2131361839:3}
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:822)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:612)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:437)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-20 03:00:14.539: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I recreate the Fragments every time I come back to this fragment, so I wouldn't mind to find a way to just ignore this error, for example by destroying the fragments before switching or something like that.. anyone got an idea how to handle this problem?

EDIT:
Okay one way to fix this is to use

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Right before changing the fragment, that way the viewpager will start a new transaction and finish it before switching

EDIT2:
One more way to fix it

```
mViewPager.isDirty()
```

if this returns true, dont switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay one way to fix this is to use

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Right before changing the fragment, that way the viewpager will start a new transaction and finish it before switching