# Viewpager inside fragment and crash on pressing back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have Viewpager inside fragment. And it was working perfectly.

Problems starts when I added animations for start and exit of fragment that contains Viewpager.

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

To reproduce issue is very easy. **It's needed to slide viewpager and immediately press back button.**
Exception is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xx.xxxxx, PID: 28590
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070076 (xx.xxxxx:id/facts_pager) for fragment FactsSlidePageFragment{435056b8 #7 id=0x7f070076}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And one more part of the same Log:

```
08-08 20:20:26.791 D/TAG﹕ Viewpager onPageSelected() event
08-08 20:20:27.061 D/TAG﹕ Fragment on pause called!
08-08 20:20:27.331 D/TAG﹕ FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem() called. position = 2
08-08 20:20:27.331 E/FragmentManager﹕ No view found for id 0x7f070076     (xx.xxxxx:id/facts_pager) for fragment FactsSlidePageFragment{435056b8 #7 id=0x7f070076}
```

As far as I understood from last part of Log, when I slide ViewPager it needs new slide-fragment. He asked it in FragmentStatePagerAdapter but as you see this call is happening after onPause call of fragment. And there are problems, because fragment is closing and viewpager is trying to do something and populate itself at the same time.

If I remove animations on this fragment, all is ok and there are no crashes. 
Also If I not pressing back button fast just after selecting page in ViewPager all is ok too.

How to beat it if I still want to use animations on start and exit of this fragment?

**UPD1:**

The only similar problem on SO:

[ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter inside Fragment crashes Application when starting Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695116/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter-inside-fragment-crashes-application-when-sta?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry to bother you after so many years, but I am wondering if you managed to solve this issue? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @ZassX I had to remove animations at that point. Maybe there is a more elegant solution now :)

Comment: Same here, was hoping for any other ideas. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This code fix the problem for me:

inside MainActivity onBackPressed():

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentBase myFragment = (FragmentBase) fm
            .findFragmentByTag(ParserConstants.FRAGMENT_MAIN);

    if (myFragment instanceof MyFragment) {
        ((MyFragment) myFragment).removeAdapterFromPager();
    }
```

inside MyFragment:

`public void removeAdapterFromPager() {
        mViewPager.setAdapter(null);
    }`